# Fixing pixelated edges on photoshop 6.0

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have adobe photoshop 6.0 and am trying to design a logo for a website that I will be creating shortly. I drew out my logo and the only issue that I am having right now is that the edges of the shape look pixelated. What I start with was a basic shape that had a white background and I selected it all with the select tool and filled in a colour. I also cut the shape out from the white background, so now there is no background present, just the shape of the logo. But the edges are pixelated and not nice and smooth and clear. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think a sample image is needed

Answer (score 1):

When you say you used the "select tool" ... are you talking about the "wand"? If you are, you should try using the lasso select or the poly select tool.

After you have isolated the image with the lasso tool, you can then save that selection for later use. You can also refine that selection with the expand or contract option form the menu and fill in the area that way. You may find that adjusting the tolerance of the paint bucket tool will help with filling in the entire area.

Another option is to create a mask layer from the saved selection and then fill in that area as a new layer and then use the blending modes to adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Illustrator or Inkscape you should be using that for your logo. They are vector programmes (as opposed to PS which is Bitmap - pixel). With a vector you will be able to scale your logo larger and smaller as often needs to be done with Logos.

If you only have PS then I would recommend working at a much higher resolution. I'm guessing you're seeing these pixels because the file's resolution is too low (72dpi maybe?)
When you create a new file make sure the resolution is at least 300dpi (I'm assuming it will be printed), and the file size the largest this logo is likely to be used. Then you can always scale it down in size.

In PS the edges will always be pixely, but with a larger file size and higher resolution the pixels will be smaller relative to your logo.

Comment: While the advice is sound, your explanations are really lacking and confusing for a person new to the terms and the field. For example, you cannot make pixels smaller: they are atomic units. Your last sentence be better if it said "the logo will be larger relative to the pixels". It is a subtle difference, but 75% of the questions on this site seem to revolve around a fundamental misunderstanding about what resolution is. "dpi" is merely a flag in the file, and the only data stored is pixel data.

Comment: Pixels relative to logo / logo relative to pixels - 6 of one, 1/2 dozen of the other. Because the poster was concerned about seeing the pixels, phrasing it so that the pixels appear smaller seems to make more sense. I didn't really want to delve so deep into explaining resolution, because that would have made the post too confusing. (Maybe I should add a screenshot of how to set the resolution when creating a new file?)

Comment: I agree it is a minor detail and something you or I don't have any problem with.